# Transforming Vertical Tab to Accordion

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to turn my vertical tab into an accordion view when the page is less than 480px and back to vertical tab view if it is not. I've tried to use `@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {}` + adding the vertical tab CSS styling but I ended up going no where with it. Then I tried searching a way on how to do this online. I ended up finding some examples but they used different methods on how to accomplish this effect. How can I get this vertical tab transform into an accordion when the screen is less than 480px?

The Link below is an example of the effect I'm going for. (when looking at the example resize the window to see the vertical tab/accordion effect)

Example: https://codepen.io/thejettmiller/pen/hqnua

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  //----------Select the first tab and div by default

  $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul > li > a').eq(0).addClass("selected");
  $('#vertical_tab_nav > div > article').eq(0).css('display', 'block');


  //---------- This assigns an onclick event to each tab link("a" tag) and passes a parameter to the showHideTab() function

  $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul').click(function(e) {

    if ($(e.target).is("a")) {

      /*Handle Tab Nav*/
      $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul > li > a').removeClass("selected");
      $(e.target).addClass("selected");

      /*Handles Tab Content*/
      var clicked_index = $("a", this).index(e.target);
      $('#vertical_tab_nav > div > article').css('display', 'none');
      $('#vertical_tab_nav > div > article').eq(clicked_index).fadeIn();

    }

    $(this).blur();
    return false;

  });


}); //end ready
 /* if in drawer mode */
 $(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {
      
      $(".tab_content").hide();
      var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
      $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();
   
   $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
      $(this).addClass("d_active");
   
   $("ul.tabs li").removeClass("active");
   $("ul.tabs li[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("active");
    });
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #9adde5;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 15pt;
}


/*---------- vertical tab nav */

#vertical_tab_nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#vertical_tab_nav ul {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background: #555;
}

#vertical_tab_nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
}

#vertical_tab_nav li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

#vertical_tab_nav li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7%;
  background: #57cac9;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444, #333);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444, #333);
}

#vertical_tab_nav li a.selected {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

#vertical_tab_nav div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  background: #fff;
  width: 64%;
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 10px 3% 3% 3%;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#vertical_tab_nav div article {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #555;
}

#vertical_tab_nav div article p {
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.tab_drawer_heading {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 781px) {
  ul.tabs {
    display: none;
  }
  .tab_container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  }
  .tab_drawer_heading {
    background-color: #ccc;
    color: #000;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 20px;
    display: block;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    text-align: center;
    &:hover {
      background: #ccc;
    }
  }
  .d_active {
    background: #fff;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<section id="vertical_tab_nav">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="index.html">Tab One</a></li>
    <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Tab Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Tab Three</a></li>
    <li><a href="index.html">Tab Four</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab_container">
    <article>
      <h2 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading">Tab Content One</h2>
      <p>Adult education is essential for Democracy of India. The number of grown up illiterates is great. All college and senior School students should come forward to visit villages in the summer vacation. Each one will teach one there. This will remove
        illiteracy and strengthen our democracy.</p>

      <p>I happened to see a one day cricket match between Pakistan and Australia at Wankhade Stadium, Mumbai. I went for a fun. But I witnessed a horrible sight. Two thousand ticketless cricket fans gate crashed. There was a stampede. Three persons died
        and twenty were injured. Administration was responsible for it.</p>
    </article>

    <article>
      <h2 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading">Tab Content Two</h2>
      <p>City Anti-pollution Drive demands certain steps from all the citizens of ABC city. All house-holders should pack the waste in a plastic bag and put the bag in front of their house. The bag will be replaced with an empty bag by the Municipal van
        every morning. They should maintain the cleanliness of the city. This will make the city pollution free.</p>

      <p>My visit to a slum area after the rainy season was a sad affair. The pits were still full of rain water. There was mud all around. The polluted water had caused various diseases. There was no home without a sick person. Small children suffered from
        stomach troubles. The government should immediately rush to the help of the sufferers in the slum area.</p>
    </article>

    <article>
      <h2 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading">Tab Content Three</h2>
      <p>I saw a man climbing down a water pipe. He had a knife in his hand. I hit his hand with a brick. He fell down on the ground and I jumped upon him. Soon others reached there and we handed him over to the police.</p>

      <p>A tragedy took place yesterday when a Matador fell into a canal. The driver of the Matador tried to save an auto-rickshaw and lost control on the vehicle. About fifty students were travelling in it. The people from the nearby villages saved twenty-seven
        students. The dead bodies of the drowned were recovered. It was a very painful sight.</p>
    </article>

    <article>
      <h2 class="d_active tab_drawer_heading">Tab Content Four</h2>
      <p>City life is full of fun. There are parks and picnic spots to visit. We have cinema halls to see movies. We have electricity which runs our factories, light and cools our home and helps us in seeing T.V. There are all type of amenities like water,
        health check up and transport. Sometimes circus shows and magic shows entertain the city people.</p>

      <p>I was lucky to escape death by a few seconds.' A bomb blasted in the compartment of Nilanchal Express. The overcrowded compartment made me to get down. Anyhow the loss was great. About ten people died and many got injured. It was the job of a terrorist.
        The government should intensify searching operations in trains.1</p>
    </article>

  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I belive this is what you are after:

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/teodragovic/pen/wqEvOV

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  //----------Select the first tab and div by default

  $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul > li > a').eq(0).addClass("selected");
  $('#vertical_tab_nav > div > article').eq(0).css('display', 'block');


  //---------- This assigns an onclick event to each tab link("a" tag) and passes a parameter to the showHideTab() function

  $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul').click(function(e) {

    if ($(e.target).is("a")) {

      /*Handle Tab Nav*/
      $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul > li > a').removeClass("selected");
      $(e.target).addClass("selected");

      /*Handles Tab Content*/
      var clicked_index = $("a", this).index(e.target);
      $('#vertical_tab_nav > div > article').css('display', 'none');
      $('#vertical_tab_nav > div > article').eq(clicked_index).fadeIn();

    }

    $(this).blur();
    return false;

  });


}); //end ready
 
/* if in drawer mode */
$(".tab_drawer_heading").click(function() {

  $("article").hide();
  var d_activeTab = $(this).attr("rel"); 
  $("#"+d_activeTab).fadeIn();

  $(".tab_drawer_heading").removeClass("d_active");
  $(this).addClass("d_active");

  $("ul.tabs li a").removeClass("selected");
  $("ul.tabs li a[rel^='"+d_activeTab+"']").addClass("selected");
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #9adde5;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 15pt;
}


/*---------- vertical tab nav */

#vertical_tab_nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.tabs {
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background: #555;
}

.tabs li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
}

#vertical_tab_nav li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

#vertical_tab_nav li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7%;
  background: #57cac9;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444, #333);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444, #333);
}

#vertical_tab_nav li a.selected {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

.tab_container {
  display: block;
  background: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  min-height: 500px;
}

#vertical_tab_nav div article {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #555;
  padding: 10px 3% 3% 3%;
}

#vertical_tab_nav div article p {
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 781px) {
  .tab_container {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 95%;
    border-top: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
  }
  .d_active {
    background: #fff;
  }
}

.tabs {
    display: none;
}

// style accordion links
.tab_drawer_heading {
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 14pt;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 3%;
    background: #57cac9;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444, #333);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444, #333);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    .tab_container {
        float: left;
        padding: 10px 3% 3% 3%;
        border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
        width: 64%;
    }
    .tabs {
        display: block;
    }
    .tab_drawer_heading {
        display: none;
    }
    article {
        padding: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="vertical_tab_nav">

  <ul class="tabs">
    <li><a rel="tab1" href="index.html">Tab One</a></li>
    <li><a rel="tab2" href="index.html">Tab Two</a></li>
    <li><a rel="tab3" href="index.html">Tab Three</a></li>
    <li><a rel="tab4" href="index.html">Tab Four</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div class="tab_container">
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab1">Tab One</h3>
    <article id="tab1">
      <h2>Tab Content One</h2>
      <p>Adult education is essential for Democracy of India. The number of grown up illiterates is great. All college and senior School students should come forward to visit villages in the summer vacation. Each one will teach one there. This will remove
        illiteracy and strengthen our democracy.</p>

      <p>I happened to see a one day cricket match between Pakistan and Australia at Wankhade Stadium, Mumbai. I went for a fun. But I witnessed a horrible sight. Two thousand ticketless cricket fans gate crashed. There was a stampede. Three persons died
        and twenty were injured. Administration was responsible for it.</p>
    </article>
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab2">Tab Two</h3>
    <article id="tab2">
      <h2>Tab Content Two</h2>
      <p>City Anti-pollution Drive demands certain steps from all the citizens of ABC city. All house-holders should pack the waste in a plastic bag and put the bag in front of their house. The bag will be replaced with an empty bag by the Municipal van
        every morning. They should maintain the cleanliness of the city. This will make the city pollution free.</p>

      <p>My visit to a slum area after the rainy season was a sad affair. The pits were still full of rain water. There was mud all around. The polluted water had caused various diseases. There was no home without a sick person. Small children suffered from
        stomach troubles. The government should immediately rush to the help of the sufferers in the slum area.</p>
    </article>
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab3">Tab Three</h3>
    <article id="tab3">
      <h2>Tab Content Three</h2>
      <p>I saw a man climbing down a water pipe. He had a knife in his hand. I hit his hand with a brick. He fell down on the ground and I jumped upon him. Soon others reached there and we handed him over to the police.</p>

      <p>A tragedy took place yesterday when a Matador fell into a canal. The driver of the Matador tried to save an auto-rickshaw and lost control on the vehicle. About fifty students were travelling in it. The people from the nearby villages saved twenty-seven
        students. The dead bodies of the drowned were recovered. It was a very painful sight.</p>
    </article>
    <h3 class="tab_drawer_heading" rel="tab4">Tab Four</h3>
    <article id="tab4">
      <h2>Tab Content Four</h2>
      <p>City life is full of fun. There are parks and picnic spots to visit. We have cinema halls to see movies. We have electricity which runs our factories, light and cools our home and helps us in seeing T.V. There are all type of amenities like water,
        health check up and transport. Sometimes circus shows and magic shows entertain the city people.</p>

      <p>I was lucky to escape death by a few seconds.' A bomb blasted in the compartment of Nilanchal Express. The overcrowded compartment made me to get down. Anyhow the loss was great. About ten people died and many got injured. It was the job of a terrorist.
        The government should intensify searching operations in trains.1</p>
    </article>

  </div>
</section>
```

What was missing/was wrong in your code:

- in between article elements I added `<h3>` tags that serve as accordion links (if you want them to be also titles for content then hide article heading when width is less than 480px) and applied `.tab_drawer_heading` to that element instead of article title element.
- added `rel` attribute and `id` on article to make "drawer" JS code work
- I edited "drawer mode" piece of JS to match your classes to add `.selected` class on tab nav link instead of `.active` on parent `<li>`.
- did some styling on accordion links and also hide them on +480px widths and did opposite for tabs navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some styles under the media query, its working fine.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {


  //----------Select the first tab and div by default

  $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul > li > a').eq(0).addClass("selected");
  $('#vertical_tab_nav > div > article').eq(0).css('display', 'block');


  //---------- This assigns an onclick event to each tab link("a" tag) and passes a parameter to the showHideTab() function

  $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul').click(function(e) {

    if ($(e.target).is("a")) {

      /*Handle Tab Nav*/
      $('#vertical_tab_nav > ul > li > a').removeClass("selected");
      $(e.target).addClass("selected");

      /*Handles Tab Content*/
      var clicked_index = $("a", this).index(e.target);
      $('#vertical_tab_nav > div > article').css('display', 'none');
      $('#vertical_tab_nav > div > article').eq(clicked_index).fadeIn();

    }

    $(this).blur();
    return false;

  });


}); //end ready
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #9adde5;
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 10pt;
  line-height: 15pt;
}


/*---------- vertical tab nav */

#vertical_tab_nav {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

#vertical_tab_nav ul {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  list-style: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30%;
  border-radius: 10px 0 0 10px;
  background: #555;
}

#vertical_tab_nav li {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  margin-bottom: 1px;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0px;
}

#vertical_tab_nav li:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  border-bottom: 0px;
}

#vertical_tab_nav li a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14pt;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 7%;
  background: #57cac9;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #444, #333);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #444, #333);
}

#vertical_tab_nav li a.selected {
  background: #fff;
  color: #000;
}

#vertical_tab_nav div {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  background: #fff;
  width: 64%;
  min-height: 500px;
  padding: 10px 3% 3% 3%;
  border-radius: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#vertical_tab_nav div article {
  display: none;
  margin: 0px;
  color: #555;
}

#vertical_tab_nav div article p {
  margin: 0px 0px 20px 0px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
 #vertical_tab_nav ul {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius:  10px 10px 0 0;
  }
  #vertical_tab_nav li  {
  display: inline-block;
    width: 24%;
    height: auto;
 }
  #vertical_tab_nav div  {
    width: 94%;
    border-radius: 0 0 10px 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="vertical_tab_nav">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="index.html">Tab One</a></li>
      <li class="selected"><a href="index.html">Tab Two</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Tab Three</a></li>
      <li><a href="index.html">Tab Four</a></li>
    </ul>

    <div>
      <article>
        <h2>Tab Content One</h2>
        <p>Adult education is essential for Democracy of India. The number of grown up illiterates is great. All college and senior School students should come forward to visit villages in the summer vacation. Each one will teach one there. This will remove illiteracy and strengthen our democracy.</p>

        <p>I happened to see a one day cricket match between Pakistan and Australia at Wankhade Stadium, Mumbai. I went for a fun. But I wit­nessed a horrible sight. Two thousand ticketless cricket fans gate crashed. There was a stampede. Three persons died and twenty were injured. Administration was responsible for it.</p>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Tab Content Two</h2>
        <p>City Anti-pollution Drive demands certain steps from all the citi­zens of ABC city. All house-holders should pack the waste in a plastic bag and put the bag in front of their house. The bag will be replaced with an empty bag by the Municipal van every morning. They should maintain the cleanliness of the city. This will make the city pollution free.</p>

        <p>My visit to a slum area after the rainy season was a sad affair. The pits were still full of rain water. There was mud all around. The polluted water had caused various diseases. There was no home without a sick person. Small children suffered from stomach troubles. The govern­ment should immediately rush to the help of the sufferers in the slum area.</p>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Tab Content Three</h2>
        <p>I saw a man climbing down a water pipe. He had a knife in his hand. I hit his hand with a brick. He fell down on the ground and I jumped upon him. Soon others reached there and we handed him over to the police.</p>

        <p>A tragedy took place yesterday when a Matador fell into a canal. The driver of the Matador tried to save an auto-rickshaw and lost con­trol on the vehicle. About fifty students were travelling in it. The people from the nearby villages saved twenty-seven students. The dead bod­ies of the drowned were recovered. It was a very painful sight.</p>
      </article>

      <article>
        <h2>Tab Content Four</h2>
        <p>City life is full of fun. There are parks and picnic spots to visit. We have cinema halls to see movies. We have electricity which runs our factories, light and cools our home and helps us in seeing T.V. There are all type of amenities like water, health check up and transport. Sometimes circus shows and magic shows entertain the city people.</p>

        <p>I was lucky to escape death by a few seconds.' A bomb blasted in the compartment of Nilanchal Express. The overcrowded compartment made me to get down. Anyhow the loss was great. About ten people died and many got injured. It was the job of a terrorist. The government should intensify searching operations in trains.</p>
      </article>

    </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Hi, Yaser thank you for looking into this, but I think you misunderstood what I was trying to accomplish. Instead of forming horizontal tabs. On resize I wanted the tabs to become like an accordion. This is an example of an accordion: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_accordion.asp